# HERE API - Place ID

Tags: here-api

Can I save the place ID from Here Places API, for an indefinite period of time? I tried searching the policy, but coudn't able to find the solution. We will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Places data is subjected to change whenever any details of the place is modified(like website, location, phone number etc.) So there is no fool-proof way to rely on the old api output for an indefinite period of time.